# start_daemon fails with exit code 7

Tags: daemon, suse

I have a daemon called `mydaemon.bin` and a shell script called `start-my-daemon.sh` that sets some environment variables and then starts `mydaemon.bin`, which in turn calls the unix function `daemon` to daemonize itself and then creates a pidfile in `$PIDFILE`.

To start the daemon under Suse 10.0 I've written an init script that uses `start_daemon -p $PIDFILE mydaemon.bin`, however in 9 of 10 cases `start_daemon` returns with exit code 7 although the daemon started successfully. Even `pidof proc` does return the right pid. In case #10 it returns 0 as it should.

Any hints?

Comment: Exit code 7 means `Program is not running`. Are there hints in syslog?

Comment: The program _is_ running, even if it fails with exit code 7.

Comment: Try to get closer with `strace -fv start_daemon ...` (insert program and args).